# Saving different arrays in a single csv file with dynamic column names in python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

My data sheet has 250 columns with column names '1'...'250'. After random sampling each column,  I want to save all the sampled columns  in a single csv file with same column names as in the data sheet.

```
for i in range(1,250):
   z=np.random.choice(df[i], len(df), replace=False)
```

How to proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe need assign back each column and then write to `csv` by [`to_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html):

```
for i in range(1,250):
   df[i]=np.random.choice(df[i], len(df), replace=False)

df.to_csv(file, index=False)
```

Another solution with [`sample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sample.html):

```
df1 = df.sample(len(df.columns), replace=False)
df.to_csv(file, index=False)
```

**Sample**:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(30, size=(5,4))).rename(columns=lambda x: x+1)
print (df)
    1   2   3   4
0  12  10   2  14
1   9  14  28   4
2   9  11  14   8
3  22   8   2   9
4  28   3  23   6

df1 = df.sample(len(df.columns), axis=0, replace=False)
print (df1)
    1   2   3   4
3  22   8   2   9
0  12  10   2  14
2   9  11  14   8
4  28   3  23   6

for i in range(1,5):
   df[i]=np.random.choice(df[i], len(df), replace=False)

print (df)
    1   2   3   4
0  28  11  23   8
1  22   3   2  14
2   9  10  28   4
3   9   8  14   9
4  12  14   2   6
```